# Reactjs: Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

The following code throws an Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function. Could someone help me with how & what am I doing wrong?

```
const KEY = {
      enter: 13,
      escape: 27,
      space: 32
    };
    
    const on = (...keys) => callback => event => {
      if (keys.indexOf(event.keyCode) !== -1) {
        event.preventDefault();
        callback(event);   //throws error
      }
    };
    
    export const onEnter = on(KEY.enter);
    export const onEscape = on(KEY.escape);
    export const onSpaceOrEnter = on(KEY.space, KEY.enter);
```

Below is how we are importing it and using it on a button

```
<button
    ref={this._setClose}
    onKeyDown={onSpaceOrEnter(close)}
    className={c("close-button")}
  />;
```

Comment: How are these exported functions (`onEnter`, `onEscape`, and `onSpaceOrEnter`) being used? Are they passed a callback argument? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: We cannot know what you are doing wrong because you are not showing us how `onEnter`, `onEscape` or `onSpaceOrEnter` are called. But the error seems pretty obvious to me: You not passing a function to those functions when calling them.

Comment: <button
    ref={this._setClose}
    onKeyDown={onSpaceOrEnter(close)}
    className={c("close-button")}
  />;

and close is a prop. Adding this code in the question @DrewReese

Comment: Is `close` defined? Are all uses of these handlers passed a callback? Can you share complete and reproducible code?

Comment: yes, close is a prop that is being passed.

Comment: That doesn't really confirm it's defined though. You can pass undefined props. We can't really help you if we can't really see what your code is doing.

Comment: Clearly the value of `close` is not a function.

Comment: Resolved it this way: <button onKeyDown={() => onSpaceOrEnter(close)} />

Answer (score 1):

the error happed because close is not a function

```
callback(event);   //throws error
```

this line of code assuming that callback is an function that callback is the close variable that you pass to the onSpaceOrEnter function.

I checked your code on my project and this works for me.

```
  const close = () => {
    console.log("close called");
  };
```

also can do this.

```
const [close, setClose] = useState(() => (x) => 3 * x);
```

and the rest is copy paste with some console logs.

```
  const on =
    (...keys) =>
    (callback) =>
    (event) => {
      console.log("on used on", keys);
      if (keys.indexOf(event.keyCode) !== -1) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("valid key is pressed");
        callback(event); //throws error
      }
    };

  const onEnter = on(KEY.enter);
  const onEscape = on(KEY.escape);
  const onSpaceOrEnter = on(KEY.space, KEY.enter);
```

```
    <button onKeyDown={onSpaceOrEnter(close)} />
```